# jump to line X in nano editor

Tags: nano

Does the Nano minimal text editor have a keyboard shortcut feature to jump to a specified line?

Vim provides several [analogs](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Go_to_line).

Answer (score 325, accepted):

In the nano editor

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>

On opening a file

```
nano +10 file.txt
```

Comment: `Ctrl+-` seems to work, too. (ssh'd in to CentOS 6 from macOS)

Comment: If I press CTRL + _  then the view just scales down

Comment: @Black, you may need to press CTRL + Shift + _

Answer (score 55):

The shortcut is: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> ("<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>" results in "<kbd>_</kbd>")

After typing the shortcut, nano will let you to enter the line you wanna jump to, type in the line number, then press ENTER.

Comment: This is misleading at best: the actual shortcut is 'Ctrl + _'. It just happens that there is a key that produces '-' without Shift and '_' with it on most keyboards. However, this is just a coincidence and 'Ctrl + Shift + -' will not work with numpad's '-' key, for example.

Answer (score 27):

The shortcut is: CTRL+_

Have a look here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1005737

Comment: But how will you type underscore directly?

Comment: @LalnuntluangaChhakchhuak dunno, i have to use `CTRL`+`Shift`+`-`

Answer (score 9):

I am using nano editor in a Raspberry Pi with Italian OS language and Italian keyboard. Don't know the exact reason, but in this environment the shortcut is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

According to section 2.2 of [the manual](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nano.html), you can use the Escape key pressed twice in place of the CTRL key. This allowed me to use Nano's key combination for GO TO LINE when running Nano on a Jupyter/ JupyterHub and accessing through my browser. The normal key combination was getting 'swallowed' as the manual warns about can more often happen with the ALT key on some systems, and which can be replaced by one press of the ESCAPE key.
So for jump to line it was ESCAPE pressed twice, followed by shift key + dash key.

Comment: ssh'd to an Ubuntu box from a Mac.  Esc Esc Shift - is the only thing that worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, on OSX Ventura (nano -version
Pico 5.09), Ctrl W (Where is) reveals Ctrl T (Line Number), and you can type in your line number at the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Linux raspi 4.19.118+ #1311 via ssh Powershell on Win 10 Pro 1909 with German keyboard. 
nano shortcut Goto Line with "Crtl + Shift + -" was not working
Solution: 
Step 1 - Do Current Position with "Crtl + C"
Step 2 - Goto Line with "Crtl + Shift + -" IS working!

I dont know what effects it. But now its working without step 1!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, for me it works:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I am using using **Ubuntu** 20.04 on Win 11 Pro with a Spanish keyboard the nano shortcut to Go To Line is: `Ctrl` + `/`.